# Mist : Getting error Couldn't connect to node? See the logs for more:

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, private-blockchain

First I started the private network and connected with 2 node . After I opened another terminal and used the command to open the mist:

> **open -a /Applications/Mist.app --args --rpc /usr/local/Cellar/test5/geth.ipc**

but it shows an error :

> Couldn't connect to node? See the logs for more[image]

*and when I click ok button it shows*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Install geth from : https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/

Run Geth

Run mist
```

If you run Mist before running Geth, error occurs. If still error occurs, try running Geth as admin.

Source : https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2761